# How to push CMT++, CPD, Coverity and Cobertura reports to SonarSube for C++ project

Tags: sonarqube

We have XML reports generated from CMT++, CPD, Coverity and Cobertura which we want to publish in SonarQube. Please let us know, if there is any plugin which can be helpful in this?

Answer (score 0):

- CMT++ - I couldn't find anything
- CPD - SonarQube has an internal mechanism to verify duplications. You can configure it by using `sonar.cdp.<xyz>` parameters (read more at [Analysis Parameters-Duplications](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-Duplications))
- Coverity - see [Coverity Sonar Plugin](https://github.com/coverity/coverity-sonar-plugin)
- Cobertura - see [Sonar Cobertura](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/cobertura.html)

Comment: Thank you for the info. But we are looking for c/c++ plugins and the plugins which you mentioned will support java.

Comment: Have Cobertura/Coverity reports different structure depends on used language? Those plugins are by default configured to handle Java projects, but you can overwrite that configuration. For example `sonar.cobertura.reportPath` is equal to `target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml`, but you can do this `scanner.bat_or_sh -Dsonar.cobertura.reportPath=cppbin/coverage.xml`.